# No alternative drivers appearing on Software Sources and manual install leads to no unity

Tags: nvidia, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

I just got a new laptop, installed Ubuntu 12.10 and am trying to install proprietary nvidia drivers. Once I understood the change from jockey, I did a fresh install and followed these instructions:

http://techhamlet.com/2012/11/install-nvidia-drivers-in-ubuntu-12-10/

But when I do, Unity crashes on startup.

My hardware on `lspci | grep VGA` is as follows

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 650M] (rev a1)

I've followed a couple of nvidia 12.10 tutorials on Google but none have helped. Can I get any specific advice?

Comment: what is your nvidia hardware? is it `optimus enabled`? post result of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

Comment: You should get bumblebee.

Comment: I have just followed the instructions on Bumblebee and nvidia-current is now installed but as far as I can tell Ubuntu still isn't using it. nvidia-settings says `You do not appear to be using the NVIDIA X driver` etc.

What do I do now?